# Javascript regex for SQL IN clause

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

I am pretty new to the whole regex thing and I was trying to make regex that will validate strings which contain zero or more:
percentage(%) signs
comma(,) signs
underscore(_) signs
number(0-9) signs

with max of ten numbers in a row

I came up with this: /,|%|_|[0-9]{10}/
but this regex is true for e.g. 123M

Please could somebody write the regex here and explain what each part of regex means ?
I need the regex for SQL IN clause

Comment: What do you do with the regex? (Precisely)

Answer (score 1):

You want to delimit the regex, so that it would have to match the entire string.

`123M` gives you a match because `123` matches and you didn't specify that you need the whole thing to match.

For this you need 2 delimiters: `^` for the beginning of the string, and `$` for the end of the string, turning your regex into this:

`/^[\%_,]*[0-9]{0,10}[\%_,]*$/`

I also told it that any number, from 0 to 10, of these characters would be a match with `{0,10}`. I also included the string delimiters `^` and `$`.